# Bootstrap-select 1.13.9 add new item option

Tags: bootstrap-select

I am trying to add new input option what allow you input new option dynamic for bootstrap select. 
Here is [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/n2lose/ch74s0xr/7/)

```
jquery 3.1
bootstrap 4.3
bootstrap-select: 1.13.9
```

Could someone can help me, please?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Because of Sanitizer released from 1.13.6, then we need to change

```
.data('content', content)
```

to

```
.attr('data-content', content)
```

And add these code before init

```
var myDefaultWhiteList = $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.DEFAULTS.whiteList;
myDefaultWhiteList.input = ['type', 'placeholder', 'onkeypress', 'onkeydown', 'onclick'];
myDefaultWhiteList.span = ['onclick'];
```